# Show or hide specific billing field on click event in Woocommerce checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, field, checkout

I have a doubt about the work done on the checkout page. It seems to work but I do not know if the procedure is correct or maybe it is possible to do it in a cleaner way.

I needed to hide some fields from the billing form that refer to an invoice request that is optional.
Then immediately after the form I hooked a hook with a text "Do you need the bill?" and clicking on it with jQuery opens a specific div. My intent was to make appear in this div fields related to the invoice request, for example VAT number etc ...

Here is what I did: I overridden the form-billing.php file and hid the default view of the billing field:

```
<div class="woocommerce-billing-fields__field-wrapper">
    <?php
        $fields = $checkout->get_checkout_fields( 'billing' );

        foreach ( $fields as $key => $field ) {
            if ( isset( $field['country_field'], $fields[ $field['country_field'] ] ) ) {
                $field['country'] = $checkout->get_value( $field['country_field'] );
            }


 //here i only added this from original template:

    if ($field['label'] != 'Partita Iva') {
      woocommerce_form_field( $key, $field, $checkout->get_value( $key ) );
    }

        }
    ?>
</div>
```

Then in the functions.php I inserted the following code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_billing_form', 'fattura_elettronica_garage' );
function fattura_elettronica_garage(){ 
    ?>
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 mt-2 mb-2">
        <div id="click_fattura" class="caffeita_need_invoice_block pt-1 pb-1 pl-2 pr-2">
            <a class="" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="true">
                <h3 class="orange mt-0">HAI BISOGNO DELLA FATTURA?</h3>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="fattura" class="" aria-expanded="true" style="">

            <div class="woocommerce-billing-fields__field-wrapper">
            <?php
            $checkout = new WC_Checkout();
            $fields = $checkout->get_checkout_fields( 'billing' );

            foreach ( $fields as $key => $field ) {
                if ( isset( $field['country_field'], $fields[ $field['country_field'] ] ) ) {
                    $field['country'] = $checkout->get_value( $field['country_field'] );
                }
                if ($field['label'] == 'Partita Iva') {
                    woocommerce_form_field( $key, $field, $checkout->get_value( $key ) );
                }
            }
            ?>
            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_billing_form', $checkout ); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?
}
```

The div:

```
<div id="fattura" class="" aria-expanded="true" >
```

open it with jquery. with this code:

```
jQuery( "#fattura" ).hide();
jQuery('#click_fattura').click(function()
{
  jQuery( "#fattura" ).toggle( "slow", function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
```

and the checkout extra field with this code:

```
function add_extra_field_checkout( $fields ) {
    $fields['billing_FIELD_ID'] = array(
        'label'        => __( 'Partita Iva' ),
        'type'        => 'text',
        'class'        => array( 'form-row-wide', 'update_totals_on_change' ),
        'priority'     => 110,
        'required'     => true,
                'placeholder'     => __( 'inserisci la Partita Iva' ),
    );

    return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_billing_fields', 'add_extra_field_checkout' );
```

Comment: Sorry LoicTheAztec , i just update the request.

Comment: if you are referring to the hook woocommerce_after_checkout_billing_form, I inserted it because I thought it was necessary for correct operation. While in the override of the form-billing.php it was already inserted.

Comment: Oh yes sorry, this is in the default billing form template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a different code version approach that display the 2 same fields (without overriding any template file):

- The real custom billing field *(CSS hidden if it doesn't exist yet*)
- A copy displayed one with the button title that allow to show / hide the field

There is an additional hidden input field that is used with the jQuery code, the field validation and when saving the field value.

Now if the field value exist for the customer, the real checkout field is displayed with the corresponding value *(and the copy is not displayed, so no show/hide feature and no button title)*.

When the field value is saved as custom order meta data, it's also saved as custom user meta data.

The field also appear in My account > Edit addresses > Edit billing address.

Here is the complete code:

```
// Custom function with the arguments arrays for the field
function get_billing_partita_iva_field_args() {
    return array(
        'type'         => 'text',
        'label'        => __( 'Partita Iva' ),
        'placeholder'  => __( 'inserisci la Partita Iva' ),
        'class'        => array( 'form-row-wide', 'update_totals_on_change' ),
        'priority'     => 110,
        'required'     => false,
    );
}

// Inline styles for checkout page
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'display_inline_styles_before_checkout_form' );
function display_inline_styles_before_checkout_form() {
    // Hide both fields (only when "partita_iva" value doesn't exist)
    if( WC()->checkout->get_value( 'billing_partita_iva' ) )
        ?><style> #billing_partita_iva_field, #fattura-field { display:none; } </style><?php
}

// Add extra checkout billing field (hidden)
add_filter( 'woocommerce_billing_fields', 'add_extra_checkout_billing_field', 10, 1 );
function add_extra_checkout_billing_field( $fields ) {
    $fields['billing_partita_iva'] = get_billing_partita_iva_field_args();

    return $fields;
}

// Add extra checkout field (that show or hide with jQuery)
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_billing_form', 'fattura_elettronica_garage' );
function fattura_elettronica_garage( $checkout ){
    $value = $checkout->get_value( 'billing_partita_iva' );

    // Active only if "Billing Partita IVA" doesn't exist yet
    if( ! $value ) :

    echo '<div id="fattura-warper" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 mt-2 mb-2">
    <div id="click-fattura" class="caffeita_need_invoice_block pt-1 pb-1 pl-2 pr-2" style="cursor:pointer;">
        <h3 class="orange mt-0">'.__("HAI BISOGNO DELLA FATTURA?").'</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="fattura-field" class="" aria-expanded="true">';

    // The field replacement (that jQuery show or hide)
    woocommerce_form_field( 'partita_iva', get_billing_partita_iva_field_args(), $value );

    // Hidden field (used by jQuery, for field validation and for saving the field value)
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="iva_on" id="iva_on" value="">
    </div></div>';

    // jQuery Show / hide custom checkout field
    ?>
    <script>
    jQuery(function($){
        $('#click-fattura').click(function() {
            if( $('#iva_on').val() != 1 ) {
                $('#fattura-field').show('slow');
                $('#iva_on').val('1');
            } else {
                $('#fattura-field').hide('slow');
                $('#iva_on').val('');
            }
            console.log('iva-on: '+$('#iva_on').val());
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}

// Process custom checkout field
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'check_partita_iva_checkout_field' );
function check_partita_iva_checkout_field() {
    // If "partita_iva" is visible we check that the field has a value
    if( isset($_POST['iva_on']) && $_POST['iva_on'] == 1 && isset($_POST['partita_iva']) && empty($_POST['partita_iva']) )
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Si prega di compilare il campo "Partita Iva".', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
}

// Save custom checkout field value
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'save_partita_iva_checkout_field_value', 10, 2 );
function save_partita_iva_checkout_field_value( $order, $data ) {

    // If "partita_iva" is visible we save the value of "partita_iva" to "billing_partita_iva"
    if( isset($_POST['partita_iva']) && ! empty($_POST['partita_iva']) ) {
        // Add order custom meta data
        $order->update_meta_data( '_billing_partita_iva', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['partita_iva'] ) );

        // Add user custom meta data
        if( $order->get_customer_id() )
            update_user_meta( $order->get_customer_id(), 'billing_partita_iva', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['partita_iva'] ) );
    }
    // If "partita_iva" value exist for the customer
    elseif( $order->get_customer_id() && $partita_iva = get_user_meta( $order->get_customer_id(), 'billing_partita_iva', true ) ) {
        // Add order custom meta data
        $order->update_meta_data( '_billing_partita_iva', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['partita_iva'] ) );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.